# Using NSObjects as keys to a NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have this BasicNode interface extending NSObject.

At some point, I need to use an instance of it as key to a dictionary:

```
BasicNode *node = [BasicNode node];
[aMutableDictionary setObject:@"hello" forKey:node]
```

This crashes the program,"signal SIGABRT". In Java, a hashmap would call a default hash method on the object to get its key. Is there a mechanism to implement in objC to allow using objects as keys to an NS(Mutbale)Dictionary?

Comment: What does the stack trace show when it crashes?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BasicNode copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee2304f000'
***

Comment: The tags that you use in your post are sufficient to describe the technologies that you are using. You don't need to specify this in your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an NSObject inheritance as Key, but it must implement the

```
 + (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
```

method, and this is the requirement for using as a key.
To implement it your own class is something like this:

```
 - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
      MyObject *objectCopy = [[MyObject allocWithZone:zone] init];
      // Copy over all instance variables from self to objectCopy.
      // Use deep copies for all strong pointers, shallow copies for weak.
      return objectCopy;
 }
```

This is from [this](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=73) blog post!

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, given the stack trace (see comments above), seems that copyWithZone is not a recognized selector?

Comment: Your class doesn't implement the NSCopying protocol. Unless you've implemented NSCopying in your own BasicNode class, is won't respond to -copyWithZone:.

Comment: ok, but in your first answer you stated "you can use an NSObject inheritance as Key because it is implements the (...) method".

Comment: Ah nice, I get you now, I'll try this. Thanks :-)